# Что в Task Scheduler считается сбоем выполнения задачи? Как генерировать сбой

Tags: windows, scheduler

Пишу консольное приложение. Запускаться оно будет по расписанию через Task Scheduler. Если при выполнении консольного приложения происходит ошибка, то как сгенерировать сбой в Task Scheduler?

Comment: Завершиться не с `0`?

Comment: пробовал завершать с разными кодами - задача не перезапукается, хотя отметка о необходимости перезапуска стоит

Comment: `задача не перезапукается` - а должна? Где об этом написано в вопросе?

Comment: А зачем тогда генерировать сбой, если не ля перезапуска задания?

Comment: Не из-за каждого сбоя надо перезапускать задание. Если сеть отвалилась - допустим да, стОит. А если место на диске осталось 5%, то наверное не надо дозаписывать. Слишком много вариантов и "за" и за "против".

Comment: Думаю, если приложение не выполнило нужное действие из-за сбоя, то задание должно считаться таким, которое не выполнилось и его нужно перезапустить через время. Вот мне и нужно сказать планировщику, что хоть он и запустил нужное действие, но оно не выполнилось.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/4td55w/using_task_scheduler_to_restart_a_program_if_it/ не оно?